# Showing that $x \in Q$ is an $n$-th power of a rational number if $x \in Q$ is an $n$-th power in $R$ and in $Q_p$ for every prime p.

Tags: number-theory

I am studying Number Theory (in my spare time) and I have just shown that the following proposition is true.

> Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ and let $x \in \mathbb{Q}$. Denote the
> $p$-adic rationals with $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$.
> Suppose that $x$ is the $n$-th power of rational number.
>
> Then $x$ is an $n$-th power in $\mathbb{R}$ ( i.e. there exists a $y \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $y^{n} = x$ ) and $x$ is an
> $n$-th power in $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ for every prime $p$.

The above statement was easy to prove. However I want to know if the converse is also true. That is, is the following statement true?

> Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ and let $x \in \mathbb{Q}$. Denote the
> $p$-adic rationals with $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$.
> Suppose that $x$ is an $n$-th power in $\mathbb{R}$ and that $x$ is an $n$-th power in $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$  for every prime $p$.
>
> Then $x$ is the $n$-th power of a rational number.

I am not sure how to prove this or how to find a counterexample. I have studied all basic properties of $p$-adic rationals and related theorems (e.g. Hensel's lemma, Hasse principle and such). Any hints on a possible route to solve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x= \pm \prod_j p_j^{e_j}$ if it has a $n$-th root in every $\Bbb{Q}_{p_j}$ then $n$ divides each $ e_j$  so that $x= \pm a^n$ with $a\in \Bbb{Q}_{>0}$.

If the sign is $+$ then $x$ has a $n$-th root in $\Bbb{Q}$,

Same if the sign is $-$ and $n$ is odd,

If the sign is $-$ and $n$ is even then $x$ doesn't have a $n$-th root in $\Bbb{R}$.

---

The statement stays true when you assume it has a $n$-th root in all but finitely $\Bbb{Q}_p$ but I think the proof is much harder.